# CakePHP AttachementComponent error

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.x and PHP 5.4 and I'm getting these errors:

```
Strict (2048): Only variables should be passed by reference [APP/Controller/Component/AttachmentComponent.php, line 106]
Strict (2048): Only variables should be passed by reference [APP/Controller/Component/AttachmentComponent.php, line 169]
Strict (2048): Only variables should be passed by reference [APP/Controller/Component/AttachmentComponent.php, line 169]
```

https://github.com/tute/Thumbnail-component-for-CakePHP/tree/cake2

With php 5.3 everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: [this](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/php/php-505-fatal-error-only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference/) can give you some clue... hopefully

Answer (score 3):

```
$file_name = end(split($ds, $tmpfile));
```

should be

```
$parts = split($ds, $tmpfile);
$file_name = end($parts);
```

you could fix that in the component and submit a PR to the original author

Comment: PS: in the cakephp core there have also been some modification in the recent past to avoid those E_STRICT errors - like https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/e4542827c85c6558833bb8ce1c8b63ef2cd12c76